# Why is Copy-Item inserting a space character

Tags: powershell

The following code works as required but includes an unwanted space immediately before the extension '.txt'. I cannot understand why.

```
$source = 'C:\Users\xzy\Desktop\source\'
$dest = 'C:\Users\xzy\Desktop\dest\'
$mydate = (get-date).AddDays($DateOffset).Tostring('ddMMMyy') 

Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Where {$_.Name -match "abc (\b\d{2}\b)"} | ForEach-Object {
Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$dest\$($_.BaseName,$mydate,$_.Extension)"
}
```

Required filename: abc 83 09Apr19.txt

Current result: abc 83 09Apr19 .txt

Comment: The commas in your expression form an array, when it is stringified the default `$OFS` a space is used to concatenate the elements. I'd use the format operator to build the destination name `-Destination ("{0}\{1} {2}{3}" -f $dest,$_.BaseName,$mydate,$_.Extension)`

Comment: I would also recommend using the Join-Path cmdlet instead of using a backslash symbol: `-Destination (Join-Path $dest ("{0} {1} {2}" -f $_.BaseName, $mydate, $_.Extension))`

Comment: @JānisŠ. OP didn't want the space in front of the extension, so `"{0} {1}{2}"`

Comment: Thank you @LotPings

Answer (score 0):

As Copy-Item accepts piped input the `ForEach-Object` isn't neccessary:

```
$DateOffset = -1
$source     = 'C:\Users\xzy\Desktop\source\'
$dest       = 'C:\Users\xzy\Desktop\dest\'
$mydate     = (get-date).AddDays($DateOffset).Tostring('ddMMMyy') 

Get-ChildItem -Path $source | 
  Where Name -match "abc (\b\d{2}\b)" | 
   Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest ("{0} {1}{2}" -f  $_.BaseName,$mydate,$_.Extension)}
}
```